# How i can add QFrame in QScrollArea?

Tags: pyqt5

I was doing this by creating QFrame() object in loop and it add in QFormLayout to get multiple Frame but it shows nothing .

````
           scr = QScrollArea()
           frame = QFrame()
           frame.setStyleSheet("background:'black'")
           lbl= QLabel(f"{name_playlist[details]}",frame)
           lbl.setStyleSheet('''background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:1.772, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0 rgba(216, 106, 126, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
                               color:#fff;
                               font: 63 12pt "Bahnschrift SemiBold";border-radius:10px''')
           lbl.setGeometry(QRect(0,170,201,31))
           lbl_1 = QLabel(frame)
           pixmap = QPixmap(f"{thumbnails_playlist[details]}")
           pixmap= pixmap.scaled(191,161)
           lbl_1.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 15px")
           lbl_1.setPixmap(pixmap)
           # nm_songs.append(lbl)
           thumbnail.append(frame)
           formlayout.addRow(thumbnail[details])
       groupbox.setLayout(formlayout)
       self.scroll.setWidget(groupbox)```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also remember that you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: `scr` is not used enywhere, you need at least call `scr.setWidget`